# prototype ajax fetching images from other domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

i have two paths like:

a) `localhost/firstapplication/`

b) `localhost/secondapplication/images`

in firstapplication i do a ajax-request to `secondapplication/html/index.html`. e.g. i fetch the whole responsetext.

in secondapplication there are some img-tags:

```
<img src="../images/testpicture.png" alt="test" />
```

my problem: if i append the whole `responsetext` my browser is looking for the images.. the link is relative, wich means in: `firstapplication/images`.

But i want the images of the secondapplication.

Is there any way to get them really easy? Or do i have to change all values of the `src-attributes` in each img tag from `"../images"` to a fix path like `"localhost/secondapplication/images/"`?

thanks for support.

im working with `prototype js 1.7` and i'd prefere a solution with this framework. thanks!

Comment: take a look at this JSONP w/ `prototype` http://teamco-anthill.blogspot.com/2010/01/ajaxjsonrequest-is-jsonp-for.html

Answer (score 0):

If `firstapplication` and `secondapplication` are on different domains the AJAX will not work due to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). As such, I have not given a response to your image problem because once deployed on live your code will not work.

Comment: you can do JSONP to get around the dif domain policy issue

Comment: Yeah mhitza i know that, and that was my initial question... how can i make it work... with the plugin i've noticed before is it possible too... and jsonp too..

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possibilities

1. Use an iframe instead of AJAX.
2. Have the second domain serve absolute URLs.
3. Manipulate the URLs when the AJAX completes.

   ```
   new Ajax.Updater('secondapplication/html/index.html', 'ELEMENT_ID', {
       onSuccess: function(response){
           var receiver = $(this.container.success);
           var otherDomain = 'http://localhost/secondapplication/';
           var selector = '[src]:not([src^=/]):not([src^=http])';
           receiver.select(selector).each(function(element) {
               element.src = otherDomain+element.readAttribute('src');
           });
           selector = '[href]:not([href^=/]):not([href^=http]):not([href^=#])';
           receiver.select(selector).each(function(element) {
               element.href = otherDomain+element.readAttribute('href');
           });
       }
   });
   // otherDomain must end in a solidus, /
   // not tested
   ```

Comment: no iframes..i had the chance to make me known to the proxy. now it works =)